# how to make an ul lay out horizontally?

Tags: html, css

An example of what I need to do is seen at the top of the Techcrunch homepage, it is the "HOT TOPIC" row of clickable items which looks like this:

**HOT TOPICS   APPLE   ANDROID   FUTURE OF FOXCONN    GOOGLE    FACEBOOK    DIASPORA**

See http://techcrunch.com/.

I looked at CSS styles for the 'ul' tag and 'li' tag and I don't see anything there using CSS that would allow me to tell the browser "Mr. Browser, here is an unordered list.  While I realize, Mr. Browser, that you normally stack the ul's list items vertically, please instead display the list items ***horizontally*** this time -- thanks."

I did not see anything in CSS that would allow me to tell the 'ul' to lay out the list items *horizontally* -- so how is the following code making that happen

Here is the 'ul' unordered list code that does this on the Techcrunch page:

```
<div class="hot-topics-container">
<h4>**Hot topics**</h4>
<ul id="menu-hot-topic-menu" class="hot-topics">

    <li id="menu-item-398682" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-398682"><a href="http://techcrunch.com/tag/apple/">**Apple**</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-394815" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-394815"><a href="http://techcrunch.com/tag/android/">**Android**</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-399998" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-399998"><a href="http://techcrunch.com/tag/future-of-foxconn/">**Future Of Foxconn**</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-398687" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-398687"><a href="http://techcrunch.com/tag/google/">**Google**</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-398668" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-398668"><a href="http://techcrunch.com/tag/facebook/">**Facebook**</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-435062" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-435062"><a href="http://techcrunch.com/tag/diaspora/">**Diaspora**</a></li>
</ul>               
</div>
```

I tried using li float:left as follows, no change though.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 li{float:left;}
</style>
</head>

<ul>
<li>
    <a href="http://localhost/mysite/landingpage.htm">
    <img src="http://localhost/mysite/someImage.png"
     alt="http://localhost/mysite/someImage.png"
     /img>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
    This text needs to appear to the right of the 1st list item
</li>
</ul>
```

FIGURED IT OUT FOLKS!  Here is what I had to do -- I did not float the li at all.  I had to float the *image*, which surprises me but hey it works I'll go with it.  Here is the code.  In this code, the 2nd list item, which is text, appears to the immediate right of the image starting at the very top of the image's topmost edge:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
   #horizUL1
   {
      list-style:none;  /* turns off the 'bullets' for this list type */
   }    

   #horizListImg
   {
      float:left;
   }
  </style>
</head>

<ul id="horizUL1">
<li>
    <a href="http://localhost/mysite/landingpage.htm">
    <img id="horizListImg" src="http://localhost/mysite/someImage.png"
     alt="http://localhost/mysite/someImage.png"
     /img>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
    This text needs to appear to the right of the 1st list item
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css that makes the list display vertical is found in:

```
.module-header .hot-topics li {
  float: left;
}
```

Float is quite a difficult concept, I find it is best explained on [A 
List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/)

The css that hides the bullet for the list items is in:

```
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Ben -- the A List Apart reference really really helps -- hopefully I can get this text to appear to the right of my image -- thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ul {list-style:none} li {display:inline}`

li needs to be `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` or `float:left`

Comment: I'm wondering if either the <a> or Firefox is causing a problem -- the suggestion still has the text underneath the image.  Could Firefox 8.0 (the latest) have a bug with this?

Comment: could be several things, I would check if the image width is pushing the next LI element down or it could be the A as well

Comment: Hi David and thanks to you and thanks actually to everyone here who helped put me in the right direction -- I found the solution, the code is above -- floating the list item didn't work -- I had to float the *image* that I was displaying inside the list item (see the code above at the bottom of my code samples).  Now, the list displays my image and immediately to the right the text is displayed, exactly what I needed -- I had to just try a bunch of different things before I thought to 'float' the image, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `float: left` to each item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it. Setting `li{display:inline-block}` is one; `li{float:left;}` is another.

Answer (score 1):

applying:

```
#menu-hot-topic-menu li { display: inline; }
```

will make the list horizontal